# Compressing 5x5 grid with values into 1 element in Java

Tags: java, arrays, grid

A task I got for school provides me with a 5x5 grid containing numbers which we have to resize to 1 element. Every number in that 5x5 grid represents a color code (0-255). All of those values are getting 'compressed' into 1 element. That element is equal to 50% of the middle of that 5x5 grid, 20% inner ring and 30% outer ring.

I have tried interpolation and Manhattan distance to calculate the distance from the middle point of that 5x5 to the edge to see in which 'ring' an element of the 5x5 is located. However I do not get the right solutions.

I used this to  find the nearest neighboring elements.

```
int posX = 2;
int posY = 2;

for( int row = posX - 1; row <= posX + 1; row++) {
  for(int col =  posY -1;  col <= posY + 1; col++) {
    if( !(posX == row &&  posY == col) && row >= 0 && col >= 0 && row < 5 && col < 5 ) {
          System.out.print(TheFinalMatrix[row][col] + " ");
    }
  }
}
```

ButI have no clue on how to get the most outer elements.

Comment: We can't guess what is wrong with your code.  Post what you have so far, what results you get and expect.

Answer (score 0):

Given 0-based rownum and colnum, the distance from the middle in "ring units" will be max(abs(rownum-2), abs(colnum-2)).

Based on your description, I'm not sure that my multipliers are right.  When you say 20% of the inner ring, should it be .2 * the total of all inner ring items, or .2 * the average of the inner ring items?  The solution below shows .2 * the total.  For the average, use .2/8 and .3/16.

```
float total = 0;
for(int row = 0; row < 5; row++) {
    for(int col = 0; col < 5; col++) {
        int dist = Math.max(Math.abs(2-row), Math.abs(2-col));
        float multiplier = 0;
        switch(dist) {
        case 0:
            multiplier = .5;
            break;
        case 1:
            multiplier = .2;
            break;
        case 2:
            multiplier = .3
            break;
        }
        total += fiveByFive[rownum][colnum] * multiplier;
    }
}
```